# How scaling and rotation is calculated from the 3D transformation matrix

Tags: math, geometry, nvidia

I have a basic question which i am not able to figure out. Can any one help me to understand how scale and rotation is calculated from the transformation matrix (in nvidia scenix graph).

For example i have a matrix:

```
{
  1 , 0.5 , 0.5 , 100
  0.5, 1 , 0.5 , 20
  0.5, 0.5 , 1 , 30
  0, 0 , 0, 1
}
```

From above matrix i know that translation is 100,20,30 and centre is 0,0,0.
I am not sure of scaling and rotation.

Thanks

Comment: Look for `affine transformation matrix decomposition`

Comment: take a look at [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214) extract the `X,Y,Z,O` vectors, length of each vector `X,Y,Z`  will give you scale coefficients in eaxh axis. If you make them unit you will obtain the rotation matrix.

Comment: Thank you the shared article helped me to understand